# I get null for EStyleSheet.globalVars

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using [react-native-extended-stylesheet](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet#value):

```
EStyleSheet.build({   
        $currencyFontColor: 'hsl(45, 100%, 94%)',
});

...

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({

   underlayColor: Color(EStyleSheet.value('$currencyFontColor')).darken(0.5),
});
```

but i get:

```
 Unresolved variable: $currencyFontColor
```

I also tried `console.log('global vars', EStyleSheet.globalVars);` and got `global vars null`

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says:

> Please note that in most cases EStyleSheet.value() should be used inside function, not directly

```
const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  button1: {
    width: () => EStyleSheet.value('$contentWidth') + 10 // <-- Correct!
  },
  button2: {
    width: EStyleSheet.value('$contentWidth') + 10 // <-- Incorrect. Because EStyleSheet.build() may occur later and $contentWidth will be undefined at this moment.
  }
});
```

your code must look like this in order to work

```
EStyleSheet.build({   
    $currencyFontColor: 'hsl(45, 100%, 94%)',
});

...

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({

   underlayColor: () => Color(EStyleSheet.value('$currencyFontColor')).darken(0.5),
});
```